# Keyboard extension no common words, no autocorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I've been working on a little keyboard extension, and now I've reached the fase of implementing autocorrect, or something that will show what the user could be attempting to write.
The keyboard is just for myself, so just danish.

The documentation says that UILexicon contains some common words, which it doesn't. It contains my contacts, and not even that works. The only thing I get is like this: `morten=morten`, where it should be `morten=Morten`. They're all like this.

Then I tried the UITextChecker, and tried this in a playground (Swift, but the keyboard is in ObjectiveC:

    `import UIKit
    var str:String = "h"
    var textChecker:UITextChecker = UITextChecker();
    var range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
    var lan:NSArray = UITextChecker.availableLanguages()
    var t:String = lan[1] as String
    var ar:NSArray = textChecker.completionsForPartialWordRange(range, inString: str, language: t)!`

This returns results in any language but da_DK, which is somewhat weird.

How should I do this? Should I download a danish dictionary and use it in the app using some kind of mysql database?
Is my code somehow wrong, or is UILexicon simply broken for the danish language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at the `UITextChecker` class.

It's pretty strait forward to use:

```
NSString * test = @"stavefej";

NSArray * suggestions = [self.spellChecker guessesForWordRange:NSMakeRange(0, [test length]) inString:test language:@"da_DK"];  
NSArray * autoCom = [self.spellChecker completionsForPartialWordRange:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])  inString:test language:@"da_DK"];
```

Comment: This actually worked. I'm not sure why the thing I tried didn't work, but thanks a lot! (Nice touch with using a danish word too :D )

Comment: The UILexicon is not intended for spell checking but only for abbreviations and names in your contact list :).

Comment: The documentation makes it sound like it should contain common words, though: A common words dictionary. Taken straight from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILexicon_Class/index.html

Comment: yes. It could be read that way. The common words in Apple terminology is however stuff like iphone = iPhone, ios=iOS and so on.

Comment: Yeah I found out, but it's pretty confusing. None the less, thanks for the help!